# Forward difference operator

Tags: operator-theory

What does $\Delta^{-1}$ mean?

I have seen it in a question such as "justify that $\Delta^{-1}k^{(n)} = {k^{n+1}\over{n+1}}$".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the inverse of the difference operator, the anti-difference operator.  The continuous analogue is derivative and anti-derivative.

I think you mean to write $$\Delta^{-1}k^{(n)}=\frac{k^{(n+1)}}{n+1}$$
(for $n\neq -1$)

Comment: So, what am I supposed to do? Does that mean anti-derivative of $k^{(n)}$?

Comment: How do you verify that $\int x^3dx=\frac{1}{4}x^4$?  You take the derivative of $\frac{1}{4}x^4$ and show that it's $x^3$.

Comment: I guess I am not clear. I am asking does $\Delta^{-1} k^{(n)} = \int k^{(n)} dk$ or not. I beg you to be clear.

Comment: $\Delta$ is the difference operator, which is a discrete operator.  $\frac{d}{dx}$ is the differential operator, which is a continuous operator.  They are analogous, not identical.